# How to set focus when there are many textbox using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I want to set focus to the `textbox` when i click the text box. I tried the below code but am not getting as expected .

```
$('#txtDate').focus();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you share the html for these fields and the event handlers

Comment: Here is my script and html ..       <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
      $('#txt').keypad();
      var txtBox=document.getElementById("txt" );
            txtBox.focus();
   });
  
  </script>
  
</head>
<body>
<h1>  Keyboard</h1>
<input type="text" id="txt" >
<input type="text" id="txte" >
<input type="text" id="txtf" >
<input type="text" id="txtg" >
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will work

```
$('input').click(function() {
  $(this).focus();
})
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried the above code its not working ..  I have developed a app for tab . When i focus to textbox and then again wen i focus back to previous text box its not focussing

Answer (score 3):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VKBfR/)**

Use `Document.ready`
 Try this..

```
 $(function(){
    $("#txtDate").focus();
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

write it using jQuery function as

```
$(function() {
  $("#txtDate").focus();
});
```

or if it also doesn't work then try

```
$(function() {
  $(document.getElementById("txtDate")).focus();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Write the code in document ready function

```
$(document).on('ready', (function () {
  $('#txtDate').focus();
 }));
```

It should work..

or you can write
as in document ready

```
document.getElementById("txtDate").focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
$('input[type="text"]').click(function() {
  $(this).focus();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not completely clear. But the following answer might make sense to you.
And write a CSS as below.

```
JS------
$('input').focus(function() 
    $(this).addClass("focus");
});

CSS----
.focus {
    border: 2px solid #AA88FF;//This you can set any color you want
    background-color: #FFEEAA;//This you can set any color you want
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, this resolved my problem without any delay

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $('#goal-input').focus();
});
```